# Why have i lost power on two of four receptacles in a room even after checking breaker?

Tags: receptacle

I've lost power on two of four receptacles in one room but the breaker isn't tripped. I replaced the receptacle and now I'm only getting a little bit of power from the two receptacles that drains after a moment. It reads hot on the tester but no power comes out. I installed and replaced the GFCI and made sure both the receptacles and breaker are 15 amps. What could be wrong?

Comment: You have a bad/loose connection/s at one or more of the outlets.  Using backstabs instead of the screws are one of the main reasons this happens.  Turn off the breaker and check the connections.  Make sure the power is off by testing.